# Bash scp failure?

Tags: bash, scp

For example I'm trying to do a simple scp:

`scp tzj21@example.co.uk:/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1/* .`

It fails when there are obviously files in the folder and simply returns `scp: No match.`? I'm fairly sure this used to work before. When I try:

`scp tzj21@example.co.uk:/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1/1.txt .`

it works just fine. Is this to do with the server I'm trying to scp to preventing me from transferring all files?

Edit: Solved. Main problem was me being inside tcsh rather than bash.

Comment: Escape the asterisk. Either put a backslash before it, or put the string containing it into double quotes. Or even better, use `rsync`.

Comment: Just of my head, have you tried scp -r tzj21@example.co.uk:/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1/*    ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `*` (to all files) on the *remote shell*, not on the *local shell*.

Any regular escaping method to prevent *pre-expansion* of `*` on the local shell would do:

```
scp tzj21@example.co.uk:/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1/'*' .
scp tzj21@example.co.uk:/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1/"*" .
scp tzj21@example.co.uk:/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1/\* .
```

Or you can quote the whole filename string as well:

```
scp tzj21@example.co.uk:'/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1/*' .
scp tzj21@example.co.uk:"/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1/*" .
```

Comment: What about if I wanted to do say, scp only files between temp_cc{1..250}?

Comment: @TZJinzo Assuming your remote shell is `bash`, *same rule*: escape the pattern `'temp_cc{1..250}'` (let the remote shell do the expansion).

Comment: There are files of temp_cc1 - temp_cc1000. I only want to look at 1-250. `echo temp_cc{250..400}.txt` only returns temp_cc250..400.txt

Comment: @TZJinzo Are there files like `temp_cc250.txt`, `temp_cc251.txt`, `temp_cc252.txt` and so on? Also is the remote shell `bash`? (You are doing brace expansion, not all shells support that).

Comment: Yep. Now I ended up copying all files (which is better than none at all). So now I have all txt files in my local directory but I want to get rid of all files beyond 250 and I can't seem to do it. I would have thought `rm temp_cc{251..1000}.txt` would have done the trick but it simply doesn't work...

Comment: @TZJinzo Whats the output of `echo $0` and `echo temp_cc{250..255}.txt` from that directory?

Comment: `echo temp_cc{250..255}.txt` returns just `temp_cc250..255.txt` and `echo $0` returns `tcsh`. I went for exit and tried this in bash instead and it works. Thanks! I forgot about tcsh...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do it.

You must pass a literal escape to scp so that the remote machine does not consider it a glob.

exmaple>

```
scp tzj21@example.co.uk:/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1\* .
scp tzj21@example.co.uk:/home/tzj21/scratch/McAdam/chains/z0.5/temp_cc1* .
```